# A docker tile server that can serve UTM XXy CRS tiles (reproject)?

Tags: raster, openstreetmap, docker

I want to serve vector and raster layers of any downloadable open world map of CRS `UTM 34s` on a selfhosted tile server running in docker. How to do such thing?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Googleing all-around - preintegrated tiles source and CRS configuration are the main pain-points for me.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

> pg_tileserv is a PostGIS-only tile server in Go. Strip away all the
> other requirements – it just has to take in HTTP tile requests and
> form and execute SQL.
>
> The purpose of pg_tileserv is to turn a set of spatial records into
> tiles, on the fly. The tile server reads two different layers of data:
>
> - Table layers are what they sound like: tables and views in the    database that have a spatial column with a spatial reference system
>   defined on it.
> - Function layers hide the source of data from the    server, and allow the HTTP client to send in optional parameters to    allow more
>   complex SQL functionality. Any function of the form    function(z
>   integer, x integer, y integer, ...) that returns an MVT    bytea
>   result can serve as a function layer.

https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pg_tileserv/1.0.8/introduction/